# Javascript RegEx validator

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, controls

I need to validate control in Javascript.

the number has to be max 12 numbers where first 7 letters are 9900000 then 0 or 1, and rest 4 numbers are free.

I already defined validator as:

```
var validator = new RegExp("/^9900000[0-1]{3}\[0-9]{4}/");
```

but it doesnt work, what's wrong?

EDIT:

```
                    var check = 990000014212;

                    var validator = new RegExp("/^9900000[0-1][0-9]{4}$/");
                    console.log(validator.test(check));
                    if (validator.test(check))
                    {
                        console.log("Valid");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log(check);
                        console.log("Invalid");
                    }
```

How it is possible that the result is always "Invalid", and false?

Comment: Your regex only matches things with three 0 or 1 characters after the first part, not just one.

Comment: The problem was in / at the beggining, when i logged validator i realized its "/\ /^9900000[0-1][0-9]{4}$" somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a {3} in your RegExp string, which conflicts with your description.

Comment: its "/^9900000[0-1]{3} \ [0-9]{4}/" Sorry, i dont know why the \ in the middle was deleted on copy, is it still wrong?

Comment: Your ` \ ` matches a literal space and then a literal space. Assuming your original description is precise and correct, then the validator should be:

var validator = new RegExp("/^9900000[0-1][0-9]{4}/");

Comment: Well, i entered the '990000014212' number and it returns "Invalid". Doesn't should it pass the text?

Comment: `990000014212` matches ^9900000[0-1][0-9]{4}; you can validate this with an external validator e.g. [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/). Could the error be elsewhere?

Comment: I suggest changing it to `/^9900000[0-1][0-9]{4}$/` to make sure `990000014212Ihazcheezeburgerz` isn't valid.

Comment: To be honest its still invalid...I dunno how it is possible. I just edit my code to show whole code